# Obfuscate a password in jenkins freestyle job in section shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, obfuscation

I have a jenkins job in freestyle mode. In the build step, I add a section  "execute shell script". And in this shell section script, I have a command to connect to bitbucket with a user et token. My issue is I want to obfuscate the token to not allow everyone to see it.
I know that this possible with pipeline but I not find any solution for freestyle job ...
Anyone have solution for this please?

Comment: [Mask Passwords](https://plugins.jenkins.io/mask-passwords/) ?

Comment: Hello Ian, thanks for the reply, I manage to do it with option "Use secret text(s) or file(s)
" in the job settings. But you right, Mask passwords is another option

Answer (score 2):

Finally I manage to do it with option "Use secret text(s) or file(s)" available in the job settings